# Is it possible to import Buildsrc scripts from a repository like nexus?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

So we have over 200+ repositories and most of them are Gradle projects currently, we add 10-15 buildsrc scripts to every project and import them into the modules that require them. I wondered if we could put these scripts in a repository like Nexus to import them into the modules directly? or to somehow create a script so that we can include these scripts from nexus into the build, reducing the scripts from 10-15 to 1.

I would love to know if people have experience with this?

Comment: Are you talking about Gradle scripts? Why not to create Gradle plugin or helper library that could be hosted in repo and simplify build.gradle

Comment: yes im talking about gradle scripts, the reason why we did not want plugins is because we wanted to introduce single responsibility in our build process because we has a build gradle file of a couple thousands lines. this is why we split it up and moved it to the buildsrc.

Comment: That sounds like a company wide plugin

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_publishing_convention_plugins.html

Comment: hi @tim_yates, thank you! I think this will help me with our problem.